# No starting estimate was successful error with coxme upon data subsetting

Tags: r, random, mixed-models, cox-regression

I have a large dataset that I subsetted and created a new dataset.
I used the following code that works perfectly

```
require(sjPlot);require(coxme)
tab_model(coxme(Surv(comp2_years, comp2)~FEMALE+(1|TRIAL), data))
```

But when I used the subsetted datas set using the following code,

```
www<- subset(data, (data$TRIAL != 5 & data$Sex.standerd.BMI.gpM1F2 >=1))
tab_model(coxme(Surv(comp2_years, comp2)~FEMALE+(1|TRIAL), www))
```

it gave me the following error:

```
Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  No starting estimate was successful
```

This is my new data structure

```
 str(www)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  7576 obs. of  79 variables:
 $ TRIAL                                                          : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FEMALE                                                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ type_comp2                                                     : chr  "0" "0" "Revasc" "0" ...
 $ comp2                                                          : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ comp2_years                                                    : num  10 10 9.77 10 10 ...
 $ Sex.standerd.BMI.gpM1F2                                        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Trial1_4.MiddleBMI                                             : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246155/random-slopes-cox-proportional-hazards) but I could not solve my current problem.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the droplevels() command to your subset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, and I found that using `droplevels()` to forget about the levels you did not include in the subset solved it:

```
library(survival)
library(coxme)
```

Change `ph.ecog` from number to categorical to make this point:

```
lung$ph.ecog <- as.factor(lung$ph.ecog)
(fit <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + (1|inst), lung))
```

Works well for the full data set. Subset out some levels of `ph.ecog`, and it gives this error:

```
lunga <- subset(lung, !ph.ecog %in% c(2, 3))
(fita <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + (1|inst), lunga))
Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  No starting estimate was successful
```

Using `droplevels()` to forget about empty levels allows `coxme` to fit again:

```
lungb <- droplevels(subset(lung, !ph.ecog %in% c(2, 3)))
(fitb <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + (1|inst), lungb))
```